# Android how to respond to ACTION_VIEW/ ACTION_SEND?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I just cannot seem to figure this one out: how do I respond to the ACTION_VIEW and ACTION_SEND intents? I have them in my Manifest file (and they appear in the drop down list of apps). What I need to do is respond to these intents and retrieve a bitmap of the corresponding image.

Right now here is what works:

```
Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cr.openInputStream(uri));
```

Then I take that uri and fetch a bitmap. However, if I respond when the email app downloads and image `getExtras()` is `null` and I get an error.

Basically I need to know what to put in here to fill a variable, `mBitmap`:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) || Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action))
{
    Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    Bitmap mBitmap = (getExtras() == null) ? what goes here :
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cr.openInputStream(uri)) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getIntent().getData()` will contain the `Uri` for which the `Intent` is targeted.

Comment: I have tried this, but that too is null. I do not understand how the stock AOSP gallery responds to the intent, but I am unable to.